# How to mock jquery ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, ready

Due to certain reason, we are going to remove jquery from our legacy app (Please don't ask why!)

However, there 1000+ of template files by designers, are making used of jquery ready function. We plan to make the following mock strategy.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // // http://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701
    (function(funcName, baseObj) {
        // The public function name defaults to window.docReady
        // but you can pass in your own object and own function name and those will be used
        // if you want to put them in a different namespace
        funcName = funcName || "docReady";
        baseObj = baseObj || window;
        var readyList = [];
        var readyFired = false;
        var readyEventHandlersInstalled = false;

        // call this when the document is ready
        // this function protects itself against being called more than once
        function ready() {
            if (!readyFired) {
                // this must be set to true before we start calling callbacks
                readyFired = true;
                for (var i = 0; i < readyList.length; i++) {
                    // if a callback here happens to add new ready handlers,
                    // the docReady() function will see that it already fired
                    // and will schedule the callback to run right after
                    // this event loop finishes so all handlers will still execute
                    // in order and no new ones will be added to the readyList
                    // while we are processing the list
                    readyList[i].fn.call(window, readyList[i].ctx);
                }
                // allow any closures held by these functions to free
                readyList = [];
            }
        }

        function readyStateChange() {
            if (document.readyState === "complete") {
                ready();
            }
        }

        // This is the one public interface
        // docReady(fn, context);
        // the context argument is optional - if present, it will be passed
        // as an argument to the callback
        baseObj[funcName] = function(callback, context) {
            // if ready has already fired, then just schedule the callback
            // to fire asynchronously, but right away
            if (readyFired) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    callback(context);
                }, 1);
                return;
            } else {
                // add the function and context to the list
                readyList.push({
                    fn: callback,
                    ctx: context
                });
            }
            // if document already ready to go, schedule the ready function to run
            if (document.readyState === "complete") {
                setTimeout(ready, 1);
            } else if (!readyEventHandlersInstalled) {
                // otherwise if we don't have event handlers installed, install them
                if (document.addEventListener) {
                    // first choice is DOMContentLoaded event
                    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready, false);
                    // backup is window load event
                    window.addEventListener("load", ready, false);
                } else {
                    // must be IE
                    document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", readyStateChange);
                    window.attachEvent("onload", ready);
                }
                readyEventHandlersInstalled = true;
            }
        }
    })("docReady", window);

    // Mock jquery.
    var jQuery = function(baseObj) {
        return {
            ready: function(baseObj) {
                docReady(baseObj);
            }
        }
    };
    var $ = jQuery;
</script>

</head>
```

Take note, we tend to mock jquery ready with the following code snippet.

```
// Mock jquery.
var jQuery = function (baseObj) {
    return {
        ready: function (baseObj) {
            docReady(baseObj);
        }
    }
};
var $ = jQuery;
```

It works for cases

- `jQuery(document).ready(function() {...});`
- `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

However, how can we make the following syntax works as well?

```
$(function() {...});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the passed parameter is function

```
var jQuery = function(baseObj) {
    if (typeof baseObj === 'function')
        return docReady(baseObj);
```

Code:

```
// Mock jquery.
var jQuery = function (baseObj) {
    if (typeof baseObj === 'function')
        return docReady(baseObj);

    return {
        ready: function (baseObj) {
            docReady(baseObj);
        }
    }
};
var $ = jQuery;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the third case you are actually not calling the ready function. As it is just bind a function in it .

```
$(function() {...});
```

So the below function is not called , you are just return an object function which is not called.

```
var jQuery = function (baseObj) {
    return {
        ready: function (baseObj) {
            docReady(baseObj);
        }
    }
};
```

You need to called the function directly for the third case, as below.

```
 // Mock jquery.
  var jQuery = function (baseObj) {
      if (typeof(baseObj) === 'function') docReady(baseObj);
      return {
          ready: function (baseObj) {
              docReady(baseObj);
          }
      }
  };
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/vnd92c1u/

I also had alike situation, a some what similar code is live for long now.